# List of installable Homebrew casks

Tags: macos, homebrew, homebrew-cask

Is there a way to obtain a list (possibly with descriptions) of all the casks installable with [Homebrew Cask](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask)?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The new way to list all installable cask packages is:

`brew search --casks '*'`

The `'*'` (or equivalently `\*`) is necessary and is interpreted as a glob that matches all strings. The quotes (or backslash) are necessary to have a literal asterisk passed to `brew search`; without them, the shell would glob-expand the `*` into all files in the current directory.

The general usage is `brew search, -S [options] text|/regex/ [...]`.

The man page for brew has the following information:

> search --casks
>
> Display  all  locally  available  casks  (including tapped ones). No online search is performed.

Comment: So what does 'locally available' mean here?

Comment: It's the local formula files which are like the "known packages available for download and installation". you can see them if you `ls /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask/Casks` then `cat` any of them to see how their information is stored.

Comment: Thanks. Assume Homebrew downloads these files when it's updating or otherwise connected online.

Comment: This does not seem to work. When I invoke the above command, brew tells me I'm using it wrong. 'Usage: brew search, -S [options] text|/regex/ [...]'

Comment: @Jan You are right, while the documentation didn't change, seems like text is now mandatory, you can add a * by adding a \* (to avoid it thinking you are referring to the content of the current directory). So: 
brew search --casks \*

Answer (score 26):

Brew search now has a --desc flag.

This lists all of them with the description:

```
brew search --casks --desc ''
```

Comment: Quick useful utilitarian answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

### List using a browser

1. Visit the website https://formulae.brew.sh/
2. Use `*` as search string and all the casks will be displayed

---

### List using the command line

```
for cask in $(brew search); do
    brew cask info $cask;
done
```

Comment: Maybe need `$(brew cask search | grep -v '==> Partial matches')`

Comment: For new people finding this page, Per Homebrew: Calling `brew cask search` is deprecated and will be disabled on 2018-09-30! Use `brew search` instead

Comment: Does formulae.brew.sh show casks? It looks like just packages to me. For example, when I use `brew search nextcloud` from the command line it indicates there's a nextcloud cask. But when I load the package list on formulae.brew.sh, nextcloud doesn't show up.

Comment: Homebrew has changed. Following limits to casks: 

`for cask in $(brew search --casks); do
    brew cask info $cask;
done`

Answer (score 7):

Run `brew search` without argument to list all of them. You won’t get descriptions, thought.

Comment: For new people finding this page, Per Homebrew: Calling `brew cask search` is deprecated and will be disabled on 2018-09-30! Use `brew search` instead

Answer (score 2):

There's a new GUI that enables quick browsing on all the Homebrew packages.

You might want to try out [Cakebrew](https://www.cakebrew.com/)

Also worth noting the analytics data of the top downloads of all cask packages in the past 365 days: https://formulae.brew.sh/analytics/

Comment: Are you sure Cakebrew supports searching for casks? I tried installing it and I cannot find any such functionality, nor anything on the web to support that claim (at the moment).

Answer (score 2):

The installable list is 7000+ casks. You, of course, can grep the result.., but more practical is to list some subset of the installable casks using `search` command:

> `brew search [YOUR-SEARCH-SUBSTRING`]

It will print you 2 groups. The first group will be installable *==> Formulae*, if any. The second group will be **==> Casks**

---

For example, if you are looking for Beaver DB browser, you can type either:

```
brew search Beaver

---- Output ----
==> Casks
dbeaver-enterprise   dbeaver-enterprise   swiftybeaver         swiftybeaver
```

or:

```
brew search DB

---- Output ----
==> Formulae
ansible-cmdb              dbmate                    lbdb                      mariadb@10.2              questdb
...
==> Casks
1password-beta                             dynamodb-local                             mongodb-compass-readonly
actual-odbc-pack                           dynamodb-local                             mongodbpreferencepane
actual-odbc-pack                           exist-db                                   mongodbpreferencepane
apache-couchdb                             exist-db                                   navicat-for-mariadb
apache-couchdb                             flvcd-bigrats                              navicat-for-mariadb
arq-cloud-backup                           flvcd-bigrats                              nosql-workbench-for-amazon-dynamodb
arq-cloud-backup                           gcollazo-mongodb                           nosql-workbench-for-amazon-dynamodb
db-browser-for-sqlite                      gcollazo-mongodb                           nosqlbooster-for-mongodb
db-browser-for-sqlite                      handbrake                                  nosqlbooster-for-mongodb
dbeaver-community ✔                        handbrake                                  omnidb
dbeaver-community ✔                        handbrake-nightly                          omnidb
dbeaver-enterprise                         handbrakebatch                             rekordbox
dbeaver-enterprise                         handbrakebatch                             rekordbox
dbglass                                    hex-fiend-beta                             soundboosterlite
dbglass                                    macgdbp                                    soundboosterlite
dbkoda                                     macgdbp                                    sql-power-architect-jdbc
dbkoda                                     mongodb-compass                            sql-power-architect-jdbc
dbngin                                     mongodb-compass                            thingsmacsandboxhelper
dbngin                                     mongodb-compass-beta                       thingsmacsandboxhelper
dbschema                                   mongodb-compass-community                  thunderbird-beta
dbschema                                   mongodb-compass-community                  wireshark-chmodbpf
dbvisualizer                               mongodb-compass-isolated-edition           wireshark-chmodbpf
dbvisualizer                               mongodb-compass-isolated-edition
deadbeef-devel                             mongodb-compass-readonly
```

the  `✔`  mark indicates installed casks.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple ways to do, collating different answers:

1.

```
for cask in $(brew search ''); do
brew info $cask; done
```

2. `brew search --casks`
3. `brew search`

You could one-line it to put results into file for later (because its really slow querying packages one by one):

```
for cask in $(brew search ''); do brew info $cask; echo "==="; done > list_of_casks.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Slight modification to the answer above:

```
for cask in $(brew search --casks); do
    brew cask info $cask;
done
```

Comment: Instead of posting your own answer with some modifications you could also `edit` the answer from another user directly. There should be a small `edit` button between the `share` and `flag` button.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not interested in installation stats, which you could get by using `brew search` answers above, you could simply go with:

```
grep  -e '\(version\|cask\|creator\|desc\|homepage\) ' /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask/Casks/*.rb
```

This will get you a list lite this:

```
zotero.rb:cask "zotero" do
zotero.rb:  version "5.0.96.3"
zotero.rb:  desc "Collect, organize, cite, and share research sources"
zotero.rb:  homepage "https://www.zotero.org/"
zprint.rb:cask "zprint" do
zprint.rb:  version "1.2.1"
zprint.rb:  desc "Library to reformat Clojure and Clojurescript source code and s-expressions"
zprint.rb:  homepage "https://github.com/kkinnear/zprint"
zterm.rb:cask "zterm" do
zterm.rb:  version "1.2"
zterm.rb:  desc "Terminal emulation program"
zterm.rb:  homepage "https://www.dalverson.com/zterm/"
```

which will be instant, rather than waiting for ages for

```
for cask in $(brew search ''); do brew info $cask; echo "\n\n"; done
```

where you'd get prettier results and info regarding popularity:

```
cobalt: stable 0.17.5 (bottled)
Static site generator written in Rust
https://cobalt-org.github.io/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/cobalt.rb
License: MIT
==> Dependencies
Build: rust
==> Analytics
install: 10 (30 days), 45 (90 days), 147 (365 days)
install-on-request: 10 (30 days), 45 (90 days), 147 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)



coccinelle: stable 1.1.1 (bottled), HEAD
Program matching and transformation engine for C code
http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/coccinelle.rb
License: GPL-2.0-only
==> Dependencies
Build: autoconf, automake, hevea, ocaml-findlib, opam, pkg-config
Required: ocaml, pcre
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 3 (30 days), 22 (90 days), 167 (365 days)
install-on-request: 3 (30 days), 22 (90 days), 167 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```