# How to get a list of brew casks in Terminal?

Tags: macos, homebrew, homebrew-cask

Already read solution in ["List of installable Homebrew casks"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930492/list-of-installable-homebrew-casks#52576039), but using all the available suggestions I still don't get a list of Home-brew installable casks.

Using `brew search`, `brew search --casks`, `brew cask search` or other similar commands I get `Error: Invalid usage: This command requires at least 1 text or regex argument.`

I know `brew cask search` is deprecated, but I still can't find a way to get a list of installable packages in Brew, *within the command line*

Answer (score 1):

You just need to give it an argument. A blank string will match anything.

```
$ brew search --casks ""
```

Comment: I tried that just now, but didn't get anything in return. Not even an error or message, just nothing, and then a new line to write a command in.

Comment: The most likely reason is simply that it's accurate -- that no casks are available on that particular machine? Try brew update and run it again?

Comment: Just updated it and ran as you suggested, but nothing :(